Exporting GEE classified images in NodeJS with APIClient ENAMETOOLONG
I am using the GEE APIClient in NodeJS to perform clustering and classification tasks which work fine. After performing any of them, I can return the imageURL to the frontend with the getMap()  function. Besides that, I am trying to store the resulting ee.Image() as an asset or as a GeoTIFF to a Google Cloud bucket.The clustered image always exports successfully, however, the classified image fails if the training points are too many (~30), when attempting to send the request I get ENAMETOOLONG.
This is my export asset function:
async function exportGEEImage(id, image, geometry, scale, crs) {
  try {
    await authenticateIfNecessary();
    //Initialize Earth Engine
    ee.initialize(baseurl=EARTH_ENGINE_URL, project='my-project', async () => {
      const assetId = `projects/my-project/assets/${id}`;
      //console.log('Exporting to asset ID:', assetId);

      // Define the export task
      const task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset({
        image: image,
        description: id,
        assetId: assetId, 
        region: geometry,
        scale: scale,
        crs: crs,
        maxPixels: 1e13 
      });

      // Start the task
      await task.start();

      const checkStatus = async () => {
        const tasks = await ee.data.listOperations();
        tasks.forEach(task => {
          const values = task['Serializable$values'];
          if (values.metadata.description == id) {
            console.log('pending')
            if (values.metadata.state == 'SUCCEEDED') {
              //console.log('Export completed successfully!');
              classificationAPI.saveClassificationResults({id: id, asset: {asset: assetId}});
              return;
            } else if (values.metadata.state == 'FAILED') {
              //console.error('Export failed:', id);
              return;
            } else {
              setTimeout(checkStatus, 30000);
            }
          }
        });
      };
      checkStatus();
  });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exporting image:', error);
  }
}

If I print the image object to be exported I get the following for a clustered image. However, if it is a classified image I get an object containing all the processing steps which size/length increases based on the number of training points, etc. It can be a JSON with more than 4000 lines.
{
  func: {
    signature_: {
      args: [Array],
      description: 'Applies a clusterer to an image. Returns a new image with a single band containing values from 0 to N, indicating the cluster each pixel is assigned to.',
      returns: 'Image',
      name: 'Image.cluster'
    }
  },
  args: {
    image: {
      func: [Object],
      args: [Object],
      varName: null,
      sourceFrame: null
    },
    clusterer: target {
      func: [Object],
      args: [Object],
      varName: null,
      sourceFrame: null
    }
  },
  varName: null,
  sourceFrame: null
}

This is the error I get when trying to export the classified image:
Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:420:11)
    at spawn (node:child_process:733:9)
    at exports.XMLHttpRequest.send (my-path\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib\XMLHttpRequest.js:503:22)
    at Object.module$contents$ee$apiclient_apiclient.send (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:19304:13)  
    at module$contents$ee$apiclient_EERequestService.send (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:19085:54)  
    at module$exports$eeapiclient$promise_api_client.PromiseApiClient.$request (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:9329:69)
    at module$exports$eeapiclient$ee_api_client.ProjectsImageApiClientImpl.export (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:14537:26)
    at Object.ee.data.startProcessing (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:21323:40)
    at module$contents$ee$batch_ExportTask.start (my-path\node_modules\@google\earthengine\build\main.js:23436:56)
    at module$contents$ee$apiclient_Call.callback (my-path\server\routes\earthengine-api.js:1260:21) {
  errno: -4064,
  code: 'ENAMETOOLONG',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

I have tried 'casting' the result and saving each processing step into a const instead of doing all in a single line but I got the same result.
const finalTrainingImage = training_image.select(bands);
const clippedImage = finalTrainingImage.clip(geometryClassification);
const classified = clippedImage.classify(trained);
const image = ee.Image(classified)

Serializing or JSON.stringify() or evaluate() the ee.Image doesn't work either. The issue seems to come from the GEE library directly when sending the XML export request.
Is there a way that the object can be evaluated or resolved before exporting it so the ee.Image object does not include the training points and therefore consist of a smaller JSON?
